# Combining tufte-latex and threeparttable

Tags: tufte, threeparttable

I am trying to get `threeparttable` to work with the `tufte-book` class. Naturally, when I use the follwing the caption will be placed in the margin. In this case, `cleveref` has no problems in getting the reference right (i.e. it correctly prints the "Table"):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Table caption}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
        Some & tabular \\
        Contents & \ldots
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{tab:foo}
\end{table}

See \cref{tab:foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I want to put the caption above the table, similar to the requirement in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57413/change-caption-in-tufte-class-full-page-figure).

Since it looks like redefining caption is not feasible, I tried to roll my own caption by defining (as a starting point):

```
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{\refstepcounter{table}Table~\thetable:~#1}
```

Using `\mycaption{Table}` instead of `\caption{Table caption}` in the above example yields:

[image]

This puts the caption in the right place, but some features are missing:

1. Centering the caption above the table if it is shorter than one line.
2. Getting the references right with `\cref`. (This could not be resolved even after rerunning the document several times.)
3. Adding the table to the list of tables.
4. Possibility of providing a short form of the caption for the list of tables as asecond argument.

Is there any way to either a) use the existing `\caption` functionality and simply change the position to above the `tabular` or b) extend my `\mycaption` command to behave just like `\caption` in the standard classes, i.e. meet requirements 1-4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** (see below for old answer):

Here is the improved version that I ended up using. I recommend to put it in the `tufte-book-local.tex` file. It defines a "classic caption style" that fulfils all the requirements posed in the question, and activates this style at the beginnin of each instance of `threeparttable`:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@tufte@margtab\@tufte@margtabfalse
\AtBeginEnvironment{margintable}{\@tufte@margtabtrue}
\AtEndEnvironment{margintable}{\@tufte@margtabfalse}
\newcommand{\classiccaptionstyle}{%
    \long\def\@caption##1[##2]##3{%
        \par
        \addcontentsline{\csname ext@##1\endcsname}{##1}%
        {\protect\numberline{\csname the##1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces ##2}}%
        \begingroup
        \@parboxrestore
        \if@minipage
        \@setminipage
        \fi
        \normalsize
        \@makecaption{\csname fnum@##1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces ##3}\par
        \endgroup}
    \long\def\@makecaption##1##2{%
        \vskip\abovecaptionskip
        \sbox\@tempboxa{\@tufte@caption@font##1: ##2}%
        \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        \@tufte@caption@font\if@tufte@margtab\@tufte@caption@justification\fi##1: ##2\par
        \else
        \global \@minipagefalse
        \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
        \fi
        \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
    %   \setcaptionfont{\normalfont}
    \let\caption\@tufte@orig@caption%
    \let\label\@tufte@orig@label}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{threeparttable}{%
    \classiccaptionstyle}
```

---

Old answer:

Digging through [`tufte-common.def`](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/browse/tufte-common.def?r=5693d340942265d7edac07d991d6595c0ac5c30e) I found that at the first instance of a float, the original definitions of `\caption` and `\label` are saved in the macros `\@tufte@orig@caption` and `\@tufte@orig@label`.

Since I could not patch the `@tufte@float` environment, I used `etoolbox` to restore the original caption and label commands at the beginning of each `threeparttable` environment:

```
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{threeparttable}{%
        \let\caption\@tufte@orig@caption%
        \let\label\@tufte@orig@label}
    \makeatother
```

This yields the exact same behaviour as in the standard classes (optional argument possible, etc.) except for the alignment. I presume the alignment is different since `tufte-altex` defines `\@makecaption` differently than the standard classes.

I don't know if this method has any weird side effects, but so far it has worked for me.