# Tufte-book: Full-width caption above full-width table

Tags: tables, captions, tufte

It seems that all captions in Tufte-book are placed in the margin.

I have a full-width table where I can place the caption above the table using

```
\begin{table*}[b]
```

but how do I specify the caption to have the same width as the table?

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,nobib,symmetric,justified,notoc]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[b]
\caption{Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
Foo & bar & Foo & bar & Foo & bar & Foo & bar & Foo & bar
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a minimal working example (mwe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change caption in tufte class full-page figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57413/change-caption-in-tufte-class-full-page-figure)

Comment: @zeroos Where in this answer is a change in width of the caption shown?

Comment: @TobiBS The question I've linked tackles the same problem: how to move the caption out of the margin. If you are fine with just changing the width of the caption and leaving it on the margin, then afaik you have to change margin size. Otherwise, you have to come up with some way to move the caption out of the margin and this solution is addressed in the question I've linked.

Answer (score 1):

I will say that the best solution is switch to another document class, but in case that this is not a valid  option  ...

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,nobib,symmetric,justified,notoc]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}\toprule
Foo & bar & Foo & bar & Foo & bar & Foo & bar & Foo & bar \\
\bottomrule\\[-2ex]
\multicolumn{10}{c}{\captionof{table}{
Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar Foo-bar}}
\end{tabular}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]